# Guardar correctamente decimales en campo numérico SQL Server y VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Veran,esto de los valores decimales siempre ha sido un problema serio para mi.
hace un par de semanas al guardar un valor desde un mi programa tomaba este formato en sql, Ejemplo: 1234,90 (Con coma).

El programa permite al usuario ingresar valores como: 1,200.87
lo que hacia antes era remplazar las comas por "" y los puntos por comas y guardaba a la base de datos correctamente

Pero hace dias formastie mi pc y cuando instale todo de nuevo, hice prueba nuevamente y ahora el formato de sql es, Ejmeplo: 1234.90 (Con punto)

Ahora si se envia un valor, ejemplo: 1,200.87 se guarda como: 120087.00

No se que me perdi de todo esto, pues no cambie absolutamente nada en mi codigo, ni en sql server.

alguien puede iluminarme la mente para evitar que esto me siga sucediendo, porque me descontrola los valores y la forma en que mi programa los procesa.

Comment: Te refieres a como se muestra en Sql Server Management Studio? Si es así, que versión tienes?

Comment: No me queda claro, el problema lo tienes en el Servidor SQL o en tu programa? Un tema a revisar sería la configuración regional del equipo cliente, puedes configurarle el formato para números que te sea más cómodo

Comment: @Pikoh el problema era al guardar.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es correcto, logre resolver eso con la configuracion regional( algo que ignoraba ). Gracias por el interes.